# How to open PayPal after rendering js

Tags: javascript, jquery, paypal

```
    paypal_sdk.Buttons({
        style: {
            layout: 'horizontal',
            color: 'gold',
            shape: 'rect',
            label: 'paypal',
            tagline: false
        },
        createOrder: function (data, actions) {
            // Set up the transaction
            return actions.order.create({
                purchase_units: [{
                    amount: {
                        value: '0.01'
                    }
                }]
            });
        },
        onApprove: function (data, actions) {
            return actions.order.capture().then(function (details) {
                alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name + '!');
            });
        }

    }).render('#paypal-button-container').then(function () {
 
    });;
```

How to open PayPal after rendering js, jQuery.

1. paypal_sdk.Buttons().show()
2. paypal_sdk.Buttons().click()
3. jQuery('#paypal-button-container button').trigger('click');
4. document.querySelector('#paypal-button-container button').click();
5. document.querySelector('#paypal-button-container').click();

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

To open the PayPal checkout, click (with your mouse pointer) on one of the rendered payment buttons.

You cannot trigger the click programmatically. It must happen from a user action click so that the browser does not block the resulting popup window.

---

Separately, actions.order.create and actions.order.capture are both deprecated so you must remove these functions from your code and change to an integration that uses a backend to call the v2/checkout/orders API. See the integration guide at https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/ , which has an example in node.js (you can of course implement it with any other backend environment)